# Xamarin.Forms: Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, io, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing a Xamarin Forms Application. What I am trying to do is that getting the lifes from a certian server directory. This peace of code will work on most of the .NET applications.

```
public static string[] GetFiles
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("www.site.com/files");
}
```

However Directory class does not exist in System.IO in Xamarin. Is there any other way to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCL's do not support most direct file I/O classes, because Windows Phone only supports IsolatedStoarge for file I/O.

You can either use [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to inject platform specific file I/O into your Forms app, or look at PCL-friendly file I/O packages like [PCLStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCLStorage/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am probably going to DependencyService route.